# How to send data from 8051 input ports to esp8266?

Tags: arduino, wifi, android-wifi, serial-communication, 8051

Please pardon me if this question comes as a little too basic but I have tried searching almost everywhere but haven't found a clue.

I am using the esp8266 module and have uploaded the firmware in it. I have also set it as "Access point" so that other modules are able to connect with it. My problem is that I want to control it pro-grammatically through an 8051 micro-controller. I have searched online and there is a lot of documentation on how it program it through arduino, but that doesn't solve it for me. I want to use assembly language to build a serial protocol that communicates the data from 8051 to esp8266 and then to the connected modules (such as Android device).

My question really is, "would it be possible to just connect TX/RX of 8051 to RX/TX of esp8266 and write a code in assembly that transfers data as I desire to esp8266? Or, do I have to do something else?".

Comment: 8051 cannot cope upto this high baud rate so you can change the baud Rate of ESP8266 by AT Command : AT+UART_DEF=9600,8,1,0,0
But I don't have any idea for how to send AT Command in code of 8051 for accessing ESP8266.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment the only documented way for a host controller (the 8051 in your case) to talk to the ESP8266 is to use the serial port (there is a slave SPI port but the mechanism for driving it isn't known yet). So you will have to make up a little protocol to send and receive commands and data (assuming that the standard support for an enhanced AT command set isn't sufficient for you).

The baud rate can go a lot higher than the default 115200bps, if you need it to (although I'm not sure if the 8051 could keep up).